# How to do different filters on different columns

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

i'am working with SSRS 2008 and my source is OLAP(mdx query)

i created a report like this 
[image]

the report return me the following data:

```
        Nbre all Products   Nbre Dell Products    Nbre HP Products


Month 1        50                    50                  50

Month 2       100                    100                100
```

what i need is doing filter for a specific columns for example: 
Nbre Dell Products show me only the number of Dell Products also for Hp Products how can i do it

Thanks

Comment: Change your MDX query so that it returns the columns you want.

Answer (score 0):

I ass**u**me that you have a field with the Product Type (I'll call it **YourProductField**). You don't indicate how your data is set up but this should give you the general idea:

**NBRE DELL PRODUCTS**

```
=SUM(IIF(FIELDS!YourProductField.Value = "DELL", FIELDS!NBRE.Value, 0))
```

This would only SUM the NBRE field if the **YourProductField** = "DELL",